# New membership tiers - how to structure?

Tags: drupal, civimember

Our board has changed our membership tiers and I am trying to figure out the optimal way to implement this in Civi.

Our previous membership was a standard rate and then a lower price for students, youth and seniors. This along with non-profit and lifetime membership used a price set of 6 radio buttons to select from.

Now, we have 2 tiers of individual membership, each with student/youth/senior rates plus an additional for-profit organizational membership. This doubles the number of options and adds complexity.

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to approach this. Do I just create a different membership type for each of the new options? How can I make the online membership form less overwhelming? Would that require using webform integration with conditionals (i.e. select type, then "class" rate)? We'd like to still track whether members are students, seniors, or youth.

An additional question is how to grandfather current members in at the higher tier?

Currently on 4.4.7, but I'm working on 4.7.x on a dev site to upgrade, hanging on  Drupal 7.

Thanks.